# Flatten array of array of dictionaries, taking only values

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have this array structure:

```
[
    [
        keyA: value1,
        keyB: value2
    ],
    [
        keyA: value3, 
        keyB: value4
    ],
    [
        keyA: value5, 
        keyB: value6
    ]
]
```

And what I want to achieve is flattening the array into a single dictionary like:

```
[value1: value2, value3: value4]
```

Probably to achieve this is using merge twice? 
I have tried with:

```
arrayToFlatten.reduce([:]) { $0.merging($1) { (current, _) in current } }
```

but I did not get the expected result:

```
[
    [keyA: value1],
    [keyB: value2]
]
```

This structure is sourced from a plist file:

[image: plist file]

Comment: Where did `value5` and `value6` go?

Comment: Can we assume that each inner dictionary always has exactly 2 KVPs?

Comment: @matt My guess: the real keys are probably different. OP made the all "key" because their values are irrelevant. As you can see, in the result, the keys of the original dictionary are all discarded. This structure is not uncommon. It could be a list of KVPs.

Comment: Actually, since dictionaries are unordered, you might get `[value2: value1, value4: value3]` instead. Did you expect that?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, all of them has exactly 2 KVPs

Comment: @Sweeper I don't but `key` for `value1, value3, value5` are all identical, same goes for `key` for `value2, value4, value6`.

Comment: @matt its a plist btw.

Comment: @John Then you should edit your  question to show that the keys of the original dictionaries do matter.

Comment: Then show the plist please. Again, show real data and real desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly, I think this is what you're looking for

```
let source = [
    [
        "code": "DZ",
        "name": "ALGERIA",
    ],
    [
        "code": "AS",
        "name": "AMERICAN SAMOA",
    ],
    [
        "code": "AO",
        "name": "ANGOLA",
    ],
]

let result = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: source.lazy.map { dict in
    return (key: dict["code"]!, value: dict["name"]!)
})

print(result) // => ["AO": "ANGOLA", "AS": "AMERICAN SAMOA", "DZ": "ALGERIA"]
```

Dictionary merging wasn't the right tool for the job. It would take the dict, merge it with the second, which has the same keys. According to the closure you gave it, when two keys clash, it should take the old value and not the one that's attempting to be merged in. So merging the second dict had no effect. Similarly, the third didn't have any effect, either. You should read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127169-merge).

I hope today you've learned the importance of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a clear question. If you had just said "here's my source data, here's the expected output," then a question like this could have been answered in seconds.

Comment: Will try to improve my asking question skills. I hope this solution will help others too. Thanks for the solution